# Hidden elements are visible while using xpath

Tags: python, angularjs, xpath, webdriver

Ive got an app wirten in angular and all xpath i make are visible in DOM but not on a page. So if I want to check if element is visible after some action I preform I cant do that, cause webdriver can see it even when test should fail.

f.e.
I want to test login form, after logging in i want to see if some element is visible. When i put invalid data, test should fail, but is still finds this element even since he is hidden.

**I want selenium to find only visible elements, how can i do that?**

Comment: Try using `is_displayed()` method.

Comment: Thanks worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

you can form your xpath in  way that it gives you only visible element. Following is the xpath for **google search** button on **google.com**

```
//input[@name='btnK' and not(ancestor::div[contains(@style,'display:none')]) and not(ancestor::div[contains(@style,'display: none')])]
```